# Powershell : Query Document Exclude Document Set

Tags: document-library, powershell, document-set, spquery

I have a Document Library contains multiple Document Sets, each of the Document Sets contains Files.

Document Library ----> Document Set ----> Files

My objective is to query all **File Name only** across Document Sets.

here are my code:

```
function Get-SPItem{
    $web = Get-SPWeb $webUrl
    $documentsLib = $web.Lists[$libraryName]

    Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

    $query = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPQuery

    #$viewFields = "<FieldRef Name='Title'/><FieldRef Name='Name'/>"
    $query.Query = $camlQuery
    $query.ViewAttributes = "Scope='Recursive'"

    $queryResults = $documentsLib.GetItems($query)

    foreach($item in $queryResults){
        $filename =  [io.path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($item.Name)
        Write-Host $filename
    }
}

Get-SPItem
```

The code above return both **Document Set Name** and **Files Name**, which going to be extra row and how can I eliminate Document Set Name?

Thank you in advanced :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the <BeginsWith> element in your query to select items that inherit from Document (0x0101...). Document Sets inherit from folder (0x0120...)